# codeigniter jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete

Why doesn't the list auto update as I type? No matter what I type the list is the same.

I would like to be able to type "wj" and it will only list items starting with "wj".

JS

```
$(function()
{
    $("#part_num_id").autocomplete({

        source: "partnum/get"

    });
});
```

Controller

```
    public function get() 
{

    $q = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);

    $this->load->model('partnum_model');
    $this->partnum_model->get_partnum2($q);
}
```

Model

```
  function get_partnum2($q)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('part_num', $q); 
    $query = $this->db->get('item_history');

    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
      {
        $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['part_num']));
        $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
        $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
      }

      echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does your query end up looking like? Seems like that's the problem here.

Comment: Instead of `$this->db->like('part_num', $q);` have you tried `$this->db->like('part_num', $q, 'after');` ?

Comment: @user1190992 - yes, thank you, holy balls thank you. This fixed it. but way? I've never seen 'after' used in the query.

Comment: before, after, both and none refer to the wildcard % and it's placement in the query. LIKE in mysql requires the  wildcard or it won't find a match, looking for the word bread like bre won't work, like bre% will. Since you're only looking for part numbers that start with the characters you type you only put the wildcard after the characters you're sending to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong since I haven't thoroughly tested this,
but I believe the autocomplete sends a GET request, not a POST request.
Therefore

```
$q = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);
```

won't bring you anything; Instead you should write

```
$q = $this->input->get('term', TRUE);
```

Comment: Both ways work the same, the query runs and displays everything regardless of typed letters.

Comment: My mistake. If so, can you tell us how far the program is working? By "how far", I mean: Are you getting the correct term in $q? => Is your model calling the desired SQL query? => Is the raw result of the SQL query what you want? => Is your program returning the desired JSON to your javascript?

Comment: user1190992 found the answer.